# MsSQL xml parse to decimal

Tags: sql-server, xml, t-sql, null, type-conversion

I'm processing xml with this stored procedure

```
select
    col.query('./AgreementId').value('.','uniqueidentifier') as [AgreementId],
    x.query('./GrossValue').value('.','decimal(19, 4)') as [GrossValue]
    into #AdvanceInvoices
    from @XML.nodes('/DataFromERP/CustomObjects/Agreements/Agreement') as ref(col)
    cross apply ref.col.nodes('AdvanceInvoices/AdvanceInvoice') as T(x)
```

The problem is GrossValue, which can be empty

```
<GrossValue></GrossValue>
```

and probably when it is, I get an error

```
Error converting data type nvarchar to numeric
```

How can I prepare it to get 0.0 instead of error?

Edit:

I came up with

```
CAST(COALESCE(NULLIF(ISNULL(x.query('./GrossValue').value('.','nvarchar(50)'),''),''),'0.0') as decimal(19,4)) as [GrossValue],
```

but it is ugly as hell

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long before `TRY_CAST` and `TRY_CONVERT` were invented there was an `XQuery` cast:

```
DECLARE @SomeTable TABLE(ID INT IDENTITY, SomeXML XML);
INSERT INTO @SomeTable VALUES
 (N'<DATA><SomeNumber>1</SomeNumber></DATA>')     --integer
,(N'<DATA><SomeNumber>1.1</SomeNumber></DATA>')   --decimal
,(N'<DATA><SomeNumber></SomeNumber></DATA>')      --empty
,(N'<DATA><SomeNumber>abc</SomeNumber></DATA>')   --invalid
,(N'<DATA><SomeNumber>.123</SomeNumber></DATA>')  --short

SELECT t.SomeXML.value(N'/DATA[1]/SomeNumber[1]/text()[1] cast as xs:decimal?',N'decimal(19,4)')
FROM @SomeTable AS t
```

Using `cast as xs:decimal?` will return a `NULL` when the value is not castable.

In order to get `0.0` instead of a `NULL` you might use `ISNULL()`-function (as pointed out by TT. already).

### Just as a hint:

In older versions, were the `TRY_` calls do not work, this was a good workaround:

```
DECLARE @InvalidNumber VARCHAR(100)='123a'
       ,@ValidNumber VARCHAR(100)='123';

SELECT (SELECT @InvalidNumber FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'. cast as xs:int?',N'int') AS InvalidNumber
      ,(SELECT @ValidNumber FOR XML PATH(''),TYPE).value(N'. cast as xs:int?',N'int') AS ValidNumber;
```

Or even simpler, just a cast:

```
DECLARE @InvalidNumber VARCHAR(100)='123a'
       ,@ValidNumber VARCHAR(100)='123';

SELECT CAST(@InvalidNumber AS XML).value(N'. cast as xs:int?',N'int') AS InvalidNumber
      ,CAST(@ValidNumber AS XML).value(N'. cast as xs:int?',N'int') AS ValidNumber
```

Comment: We had to wait for you to come up with a better solution based on an XQuery :) +1

Answer (score 2):

You can try get a VARCHAR value from the element, use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql) to decimal, and use ISNULL to get 0.0 if the value is NULL.

```
ISNULL(TRY_CAST(x.query('./GrossValue').value('.','VARCHAR(20)') AS DECIMAL(19,4)),.0) AS [GrossValue]
```

About as ugly I suppose.

Comment: This works, but is limited to SQL Server 2012+ (upvote from my side)