# Where clause fails when used with a 'convert' function

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, type-conversion, where-clause

I am converting a varchar field representing a date to datetime, and using it withing `"where - between"` clause.

I get:

> Conversion failed when converting date and/or time from character
>   string

My `where` clause is:

```
select
screen_date
from d8003
where convert(datetime, screen_date, 120) between '6/1/2018' and '12/31/2018'
```

How do I fix this problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [TRY_CAST](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/try-cast-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017) if you're unsure if the value can actually be converted.

But be advised that the fact that you are receiving this error probably points to a problem with certain records in your column. Only use TRY_CAST if you only care about getting the records where the varchar column can actually can be converted to a datetime.

```
SELECT
    [screen_date]
FROM
    [d8003]
WHERE
    TRY_CAST([screen_date] AS DATETIME) BETWEEN '6/1/2018' AND '12/31/2018'
```

Answer (score 2):

Try using the following syntax (use YYYYMMDD date format instead of MM/DD/YYYY) :

```
select
screen_date
from d8003
where convert(datetime, screen_date, 120) between '20180601' and '20181231'
```

If you still get the same error then check that you are using the right date format code:

- [Date and Time Conversions Using SQL Server](https://www.mssqltips.com/sqlservertip/1145/date-and-time-conversions-using-sql-server/)

Comment: @deGuza what is the date format stored in screen_date column

Comment: The screen_date column is stored as "varchar"

Comment: @deGuza i know but what is the date format. Are values stored like '31/12/1980' or '12/31/1989' or else?

Comment: @deGuza try using 101 or 102

Comment: * The Screen_Date is appearing as "5/30/2018".

* Using 101 or 102 did not work, either.

Answer (score 0):

Pre-2005 there were very limited error handling abilities.
For SQL 2005+ this should work

```
declare 
     @date_value varchar(50)
    ,@tmp datetime;
declare x cursor local fast_forward 
for
select screen_date from d8003

open x;
fetch next from x into @date_value;
while @@fetch_status = 0
    begin
        begin try
            set @tmp = convert(datetime,@date_value, 120)
        end try
        begin catch
            select 'This one is bad! Please fix me!! (' + rtrim(@date_value) + ')' bad_values;
        end catch
        fetch next from x into @date_value;
    end
close x;
deallocate x;
GO
```

This will return your bad data in SQL 2012+
try_convert, will return a null on non-convertible strings.

```
select 
    try_convert(datetime, screen_date, 120) mytryconvert
    ,screen_date
from d8003
where try_convert(datetime, screen_date, 120) is null
```

You can correct the data manually or inline with string manipulation.

Comment: Unfortunately, the try_convert function does not seem to be available on my version of SQL

Comment: which version of SQL Server are you using? I added a way to get the same data that should work back to SQL 2005. SQL 2000 didn't have good error handling.

Comment: Starting with v2005 there's a `XQuery`-hack, simulating `TRY_CAST()`. Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48344552/5089204) answer or an even shorter appraoch [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53279357/5089204). It will allow for inlined casts without an error being thrown, just returning `NULL` instead. But there is no equivalent for `TRY_CONVERT` and its style parameter...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the suggestions and assistance you have offered. I am happy to tell you that I found the solution. Here is what my code is:

where try_cast(screen_date as smalldatetime) between '2018-06-01' and '2018-12-31'

This was a suggestion from a colleague who has many years of experience. (I just started coding in SQL ....)

This was a suggestion from one of you earlier, I am not sure why it did not work then.

Deguza

Comment: Hi deGuza, I'm glad that you found a solution! Please be so kind to close this question by accepting the answer you like most and please use your right to vote on any contribution you think is worth it. Happy Coding!

Comment: One hint: It was better to use `'20181231'` instead of `'2018-12-31'`. The hyphen-separated format is - in certain situations - culture dependant. A value like `2018-02-01` might turn out as *2nd of January* on a different system (while the value above would throw an exception).